# Connect CosmosDB and exceute a query using azure powershell

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to connect to CosmosDB in Azure Portal to fetch data using a query. I need to do this using Azure Powershell (Runbook). Please suggest how to establish connection and execute some random query using Azure Powershell.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The [Cosmos DB](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB) PowerShell module from the gallery works great for that.

```
$cosmosDBAccountName = "..."
$cosmosDBDatabaseName = "..."
$cosmosDBContainerName = "..."

# First get your account key

$cosmosDBAccountKey = Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $cosmosDBAccountName

# Then establish a context

$primaryKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $cosmosDBAccountKey -AsPlainText -Force
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $cosmosDBAccountName -Database $cosmosDBDatabaseName -Key $primaryKey

# Finally issue your query

$query = "SELECT * FROM customers c WHERE c.deviceid = '0' ORDER BY c.windowend DESC"
(Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $cosmosDBContainerName -Query $query) | Select-Object {$_.deviceid,$_.jobname}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cosmosDBAccountKey = Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $accountName
$key = $cosmosDBAccountKey.PrimaryMasterKey

$primaryKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $key -AsPlainText -Force
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -Key $primaryKey
  Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $containerName
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to call Cosmos DB using it's [REST API from PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/PowerShellRestApi). The link will take you to samples that show simple point operations. You will need to reference the REST API for [query here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents).

Another option may be to explore [creating a custom cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-write-a-simple-cmdlet?view=powershell-7.1) where you can use the Cosmos DB .NET SDK to query your data then return via your custom cmdlet.